# Converting an entire dataframe's values to unique integers for doing a fisher's test

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to change my string values to unique integer IDS for an entire dataframe, this is a simplified version of what I want to do. The real one has 20+ columns and 100,000 + rows. I need to convert this to do a fisher test per row which needs to differentiate between unique integers to see a difference between column groups.

***X*** **col1 col2 col3**

***1***  0/0  1/1  0/0

***2***  0/2  0/0  1/1

***3***  1/2  0/2  1/1

***4***  0/0  0/0  0/0

to

***X*** **col1 col2 col3**

***1***  1   2    1

***2***  3   1    2

***3***  4   3    2

***4***  1   1    1

Tried to factorize, but couldn't figure out how to do this for an entire dataframe like this, could only do this for a columns with the following code: df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]).

What work too is to just do it per row as its parsed per row.

Comment: So use `applymap` for the whole dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.rank` with `method='dense'`. Each unique string will be assigned an unique number/rank

```
df_final = df.set_index('X').rank(method='dense').astype(int)

Out[244]:
   col1  col2  col3
X
1     1     3     1
2     2     1     2
3     3     2     2
4     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['0/0', '1/1', '0/0'], ['0/2', '0/1', '1/1'], ['1/2', '0/2', '1/1'], ['0/0', '0/0', '0/0']])

d = {n:m for m, n in enumerate(list(set([j for i in df.values.tolist() for j in i])))}

df_new = df.replace(d)
```

Input:

```
     0    1    2
0  0/0  1/1  0/0
1  0/2  0/1  1/1
2  1/2  0/2  1/1
3  0/0  0/0  0/0
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2
0  2  4  2
1  1  3  4
2  0  1  4
3  2  2  2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this using apply function

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['0/0', '1/1', '0/0'], ['0/2', '0/0', '1/1'], ['1/2', '0/2', '1/1'], ['0/0', '0/0', '0/0']], columns=('col1', 'col2', 'col3'))

df2 = df.apply(lambda s: [sum(map(int,x.split("/"))) for x in s])
df2[df2==0] = 1
df2
```

**Result**

```
 col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     1
1     2     1     2
2     3     2     2
3     1     1     1
```